# Python XPath that starts with X and ends with zero or the lowest number

Tags: python, xpath

I would be really grateful if someone could give me a hand with writing an XPath that achieves the following:

- Finds an element with the following id: 'revit_form_Button_50' where the number constantly changes (could be 30/40 but it seems like the first one on the page always ends with 0) and also has the title "Daily Tech Totals / Daily Tech Totals / Employee Daily Totals Report"
- OR Finds and element like this: 'revit_form_Button_'+'mininumnumber' and has the tile: "Daily Tech Totals / Daily Tech Totals / Employee Daily Totals Report"

Any approach would help me tremendously.

My first two failed attempts:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'revit_form_Button_' ) and ends-with(@id,'0')]").click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[boolean(number(substring-before(substring-after(@id, 'revit_form_Button_'), '0')))]").click()
```

[image]

```
<div id="reporting_grid_CellReportTitle_10" class="rptCellReportTitle" widgetid="reporting_grid_CellReportTitle_10">
    <div dojoattachpoint="divReportTitle" class="rptCellReportTitleSpanNode"><span class="dijit dijitInline dijitReset revitButtonHideBackground revitButton" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode,titleNode,stateNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="revit_form_Button_30_label" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="revit_form_Button_30" widgetid="revit_form_Button_30" style="position: relative; user-select: none;">
    <span class="dijitReset revitIconNode dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span class="dijitReset dijitButtonText" id="revit_form_Button_30_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" style="padding-left: 0px; text-transform: none;"><b>Daily Tech Totals / Daily Tech Totals / Employee Daily Totals Report</b></span>
    <span class="dijitReset revitIconNode revitIconRightNode dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconRightNode"></span>
    <input type="button" value="" class="dijitOffScreen" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode">
</span></div>
    <div dojoattachpoint="divNotes" class="rptCellReportTitleNotesNode"></div>
    <div dojoattachpoint="divSchedule" class="rptCellReportTitleScheduleNode"></div>
</div>

<div id="reporting_grid_CellReportTitle_11" class="rptCellReportTitle" widgetid="reporting_grid_CellReportTitle_11">
    <div dojoattachpoint="divReportTitle" class="rptCellReportTitleSpanNode"><span class="dijit dijitInline dijitReset revitButton revitButtonHideBackground" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode,titleNode,stateNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="revit_form_Button_31_label" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="revit_form_Button_31" widgetid="revit_form_Button_31" style="position: relative; user-select: none;">
    <span class="dijitReset revitIconNode dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span class="dijitReset dijitButtonText" id="revit_form_Button_31_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" style="padding-left: 0px; text-transform: none;"><b>Daily Tech Totals / Daily Tech Totals / Employee Daily Totals Report</b></span>
    <span class="dijitReset revitIconNode revitIconRightNode dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconRightNode"></span>
    <input type="button" value="" class="dijitOffScreen" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode">
</span></div>
    <div dojoattachpoint="divNotes" class="rptCellReportTitleNotesNode"></div>
    <div dojoattachpoint="divSchedule" class="rptCellReportTitleScheduleNode"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Second one should work. Can you share exception?

Comment: The second XPath would also find `revit_form_Button_401`

Comment: Yes, but it's not quite clear what is the range of possible numbers and what does OP mean by *"failed attempts"*

Comment: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[starts-with(@id,'revit_form_Button_' ) and ends-with(@id,'0')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[starts-with(@id,'revit_form_Button_' ) and ends-with(@id,'0')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @Andresson It means I cannot get it to work. It's usually a 2 digit number. The first Report on the page starts ends in 0 (e.g. 30, 40, 50, 60). I haven't see it go to 100 but I would look for the lowest number just to be safe.

Comment: @iCosmin , I mean exception for second code. Also clarify the order of numbers? Does it always straight ascending, e.g. `30`, `31`, `32`, `40`, `45`, `50`, etc... or mixed as `15`, `30`, `18`, `3`... ?

Comment: @Andersson For some strange reason I don't get any exception code on the second code. It just exits without any error but does not perform the .click() operation. I ran it a few times and it's always straight ascending but it could start with a 5, then with a 3 and then with the 4.(e.g. first attempt [50, 51, 52 etc], second attempt [30, 31, 32 etc], third attempt [40, 41, 42 etc.]) I just need to get the most recent one and it is usually the one that ends in 0). I appreciate the help.

Comment: @iCosmin , actually, `find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'revit_form_Button_' )"]).click()` will **always click the first found button in DOM**, so if you need to select the very first one - you don't need additional predicates

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ends-with` in [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions), but you can use

```
"//*[starts-with(@id,'revit_form_Button_' ) and substring(@id,string-length(@id)) = '0']"
```

To satisfy the additional condition

> and also has the title "Daily Tech Totals / Daily Tech Totals / Employee Daily Totals Report"

add a clause like

```
child::*[text() = 'full content of the child element here']
```

or

```
child::*[contains(text(),'text to match here')]
```

to your XPath. In you example, the child element was `<b>`. So, you could also write `child::b` instead of `child::*`.

Putting it all together:

```
"//*[starts-with(@id,'revit_form_Button_')
    and substring(@id,string-length(@id)) = '0'
    and child::*[text() = 'Daily Tech Totals / Daily Tech Totals / Employee Daily Totals Report']
]"
```

This is one single XPath expression. Broken into several lines for readability, but could be a single line.

Comment: I have tried only the first part without the additional condition and I get the following: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable`. If I use the full one is not valid. `SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[starts-with(@id,'revit_form_Button_') and substring(@id,string-length(@id)) = '0' and child::*[text() = 'Daily Tech Totals / Daily Tech Totals / Employee Daily Totals Report']' is not a valid XPath expression.` Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: `element not interactable` looks like you are not allowed to `click()` that `<span>`. That should be related to selenium, not to XPath. For the second issue, you are missing a closing `]`. There are two nested predicates in this expression which both need to be closed. See end of third line and last line of my example.

Comment: Thanks for helping me get a sense of how to create the XPath. However it still cannot locate the element after I put everything together: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[starts-with(@id,'revit_form_Button_') and substring(@id,string-length(@id)) = '0' and child::*[text() = 'Daily Tech Totals / Daily Tech Totals / Employee Daily Totals Report']]"}` Can you please edit your answer so I can accept it when it works?

Comment: It works if I remove this part `and substring(@id,string-length(@id)) = '0'`. Not sure why it does not like the second argument. I appreciate your support!

Comment: In XPath, substring index is 1-based, so, `string-length(s)` indexes the last character of a string `s`. This should definitively work. I tried the XPath as part of a standalone XML transformation (XSLT) using a COTS tool (actually XmlSpy, but I now checked the free [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) to process this successfully too). I am sure these implementations are standard compliant. The implementation in Python's lxml _should_ be too, but who knows?